# Replacing particular occurrence of a string with comment

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed, awk

I am trying to replace a particular xml statement and making it as a comment.I am trying for some linux awk,sed or any regular grammer expression,but completely stucked is therey anyway by which i can achieve this task.Below is the scenario i am looking for.

**For Example**
I have a n numbers of xml files. I want to replace a statement which has a word **"Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item"** and should get replace  with comment statement. 
suppose the statement is ----

```
<Parameter name="RelationshipName1" direction="in" eval="constant" type="string">Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item</Parameter>
```

.....as this statement contains the word **"Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item"** i will replace this statement as a comment.So i want it to get replaced as

```
<!--Parameter name="RelationshipName1" direction="in" eval="constant" type="string">Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item</Parameter-->
```

Further all such a statement in all the xml files should get replaced as a commented xml statement.Below is the pattern in which they might occcur.So how should i go about it.I know one needs to be an adept in the regular expression,because it's the only way to achieve.
......................................
This statement can be there in n number of xml files.
File:a.xml

```
<Parameter name="RelationshipName1" direction="in" eval="constant" type="string">Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item</Parameter>
<Parameter direction="in" eval="constant" type="string" name="RelationshipName3">Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item</Parameter>
<Parameter name="RelationshipName" direction="in" eval="constant" type="string">Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item</Parameter>
<Parameter direction="in" name="RelationshipName10" type="string" eval="constant">Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item</Parameter>
<Parameter direction="in" name="RelationshipName11" type="string" eval="constant">Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item</Parameter>
<Parameter direction="in" eval="constant" type="string" name="RelationshipName5">Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item</Parameter>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An awk version:

```
awk '/Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item/ {sub(/^</,"<!--");sub(/>$/,"-->")}1' a.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`:

```
sed '/Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item/ s/<\(.*\)>/<!--\1-->/' inputfile
```

would comment all lines containing the string `Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item`.

If you want to modify the file in-place, add the `-i` option:

```
sed -i '/Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item/ s/<\(.*\)>/<!--\1-->/' inputfile
```

If this is to be performed for all `.xml` files in a directory, use `find` and `-exec`:

```
find /some/dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.xml" -exec sed -i '/Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item/ s/<\(.*\)>/<!--\1-->/' {} \;
```

(Remove `-maxdepth 1` from the `find` command if you want to do it recursively.)

Comment: This adds extra data.  Requested O/P `<!--Par` your O\P `<!--<Par`

Comment: @devnull you rock man!! thank you. Where can i learn about regular expression,especially the part which does remove anything which comes back-in-front of Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item.I mean the string s/<\(.*\)>/<!--\1-->/  part.

Comment: @NishitaPatwardhan `\1` is a backreference.  [This](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Backreferences_002c-in-regular-expressions-103) part of the sed manual explains it.

Comment: To elaborate further the sed expression performs the substitution on lines matching `Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item`.

Comment: thanks !!...and more question..if i don't want to add any comment and just put the null in place of "Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item"

Comment: Try `s/Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item// filename`

Comment: thanx..it tried like these find .  -type f -name "*.xml" -exec sed -i '/Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item/ s/Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item//' {} \; and it has deleted those lines..i don't want to do that...i just want to replace it...i mean it shud be like <Parameter name="RelationshipName1" direction="in" eval="constant" type="string"></Parameter>  but it seems that the above line command removes that statement itself from the file. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use regular expressions to parse XML. Use a proper parser. For example, using [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```sh
my $search = "Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item" ;
for my $file in { @ARGV } {
    open $file ;
    for my $p in //Parameter[text() = $search]
        xinsert comment { $p->toString } replace $p ;
    save :b ;
}
```

If you want to delete the text, too, you can change the inner loop to

```sh
    for my $p in //Parameter[text() = $search] {
        delete $p/text() ;
        xinsert comment { $p->toString } replace $p ;
    }
```

Comment: just one modifiction hint, if i want to delete the "Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item" i.e. instead of <!--Parameter name="RelationshipName1" direction="in" eval="constant" type="string">Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item</Parameter--> i should get <Parameter name="RelationshipName1" direction="in" eval="constant" type="string"></Parameter> . basically here is been replaced by "null".

Comment: hey thanx....but it's giving me an error cd workflow
for my $p in//Parameter[text() = $PROCUREMENT_LV_DF_SOI] {
        delete $p/text() ;
        xinsert comment { $p->toString } replace $p ;   i am working on unix and have a workflow directory which contains more than 40 files including subdirectories
    }

Comment: error here:./removeRelation.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$p'
./removeRelation.sh: line 4: `for my $p in//Parameter[text() = $PROCUREMENT_LV_DF_SOI] {'
where line 4 is for my $p in//Parameter[text() =

Comment: @NishitaPatwardhan: The script must be run in `xsh`, not `sh`.

Answer (score 1):

check with below sed equation it will comment

```
sed -i 's/\(<.*Distribution_Facilities_carrying_Item.*>\)/<!--\1-->/' filename.xml
```